# Template specialization with another template

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, template-classes

Say I have two template classes

```
template < class T >
class Foo
{
    /**/
};
```

and

```
template < class T >
class Bar
{
     /**/
};
```

how can I specialise `Foo` with `Bar<T>` ??
what is the syntax??
is it

```
template<>
template<class T>
class Foo<Bar<T>>
{ /**/ };
```

or

```
template<class T>
class Foo<Bar<T>>
{ /**/ };
```

or any other syntax??

Comment: `template<typename T> class Foo<Bar<T>>` is the right syntax.

Comment: Have you tried it? http://ideone.com/gTorRO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax is the last one:

```
template<class T>
class Foo<Bar<T>>
{
     /* Your implementation of this partial specialization. */
};
```